# Qual é a forma correta de se executar um aplicativo em um servidor linux usando PHP?

Tags: php, linux, servidor

Boa tarde, estou necessitando executar uma aplicação construída nativamente para servidores linux utilizando o php.

Possuo um script php que executa uma aplicação no servidor linux criando alguns arquivos necessários para o prosseguimento da aplicação.

Ao executar o script pelo terminal o programa é executado corretamente gerando os arquivos necessários. Porém ao executá-lo pelo navegador o mesmo script não executa a aplicação.

Já utilizei as funções system, exec, shell_exec, passthru porém nenhuma executou devidamente a aplicação. Gostaria de saber qual é a forma correta de se executar aplicações através do php e como obter e tratar os respectivos retornos.

Exemplo que estou utilizando :

```
<?php
   exec('/home/dados/controll/ncolinux');
?>
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44556/discussion-on-question-by-isaque-fernando-qual-e-a-forma-correta-de-se-executar)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Olá! Quando você executa o script pelo navegador, é o usuário do servidor web que executa esse script. Por exemplo: Se você estiver usando um servidor Apache, ele executa com um usuário chamado apache. Então você precisa dar privilégios suficiente para que esse usuário possa executar a aplicação.

Para pegar o retorno do que foi executado, use a função `shell_exec()`, ela retorna uma string, que é o resultado do comando executado.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Você sabe me informar como altero estas configurações e permissões do usuário do apache 2 ?

Comment: Mudar as configuração de permissões de apache talvez não seja uma boa. Tenta mudar a permissão do arquivo que precisa ser executado , usando `chmod`

Comment: Lucas, já dei permissão para o arquivo. Obrigado.

Comment: Complementando a resposta do Lucas, voce precisa adicionar o usuario (provavelmente www-data) que o php usa no grupo que tem permissao para executar o aplicativo. No seu código você pode passar o comando shell "whoami" para ver qual o usuario que o php utiliza. E para o aplicativo você pode acessar a pasta dele e listar usando ls-lah para ver qual grupo tem permissao sobre aquele arquivo.

Comment: @JaoAssy, realmente o usuário que o php está utilizando é o www-data. Porém eu habilitei as permissões ao máximo.

Comment: Você ja adicionou o www-data no grupo de permissao correspondente da sua aplicação? se sim, é preciso somente reiniciar a máquina, talvez re-logar resolva.

Comment: @JaoAssy, troquei a permissão da pasta com o comando `chown www-data nome_pasta` e reiniciei a maquina. Infelizmente ainda não resolveu.

Comment: Não precisa trocar o dono da pasta, somente adicionar o www-data no grupo, executa o comando ls -lah você verá 2 nomes, da esquerda para direita, o primeiro é o usuário e o segundo é o grupo. Execute agora o comando groups www-data para ver quais grupos o www-data pertence, se ele nao tiver no grupo do arquivo adicione com o seguinte comando: useradd -G nomedogrup www-data, reinicie e teste novamente.

Comment: @JaoAssy, há a possibilidade de executar o arquivo com o usuário `www-data` pelo terminal usando o comando `$ php arquivo.php` ?

Comment: sudo -H -u www-data aplicacao

Comment: Pela linha de comando deu certo @JaoAssy. Mas pelo navegador ainda não executa.

Comment: posta as permissoes da aplicacao, os grupos que o www-data estao e o erro caso tenha quando voce tenta executar via php

Comment: @JaoAssy, a permissão do arquivo `-rwxrwxrwx`. O grupo do usuário `www-data : www-data root`. Erro não retornou nenhum. Desculpe o atraso na resposta.